How to to configure lsp, formatter and linter for laravel and vuejs in LazyVim
I have tried to configure LazyVim to code a laravel project with vuejs framework. I've tried lazyextras, configuring lsp and mason, installing coc-nvim, coc-volar... I have already tried everything with no success.
And I have not found any tutorial for neovim newbies ... any help, please? ... tutorials more than 6 months ago are already, aren't they?
Thank you!

Not sure if you have already solved your problem. However, I think that either
ThePrimeTimeAgen has a 3 part video of how to setup using lazyvim with LSP's:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWWxwwUsPNw
Or "Teej" with him building a project from LSP implementation for Laravel, etc.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOR3IqrLEyI&list=PLDWRoFV4JjSQ1QRD0Wwpg845o2h-z8IBt
Both uses nvim. And although this doesn't answer your question, I hope it puts you on the right path.

Thank you ... i'll watch them! ..and no, I haven't solved my problem yet  :)
